# How to pass the firestore snapshot collection data to child component in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I am getting this error `The instance member 'meetings' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`, when I pass the `CollectionReference` of firebase from Home.dart to MeetingList.dart. Here is my sample code.

> Home.dart

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
  User currentUser;
  String userId;
  Home({this.currentUser, this.userId});
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  CurrentUser userInfo;
  DocumentSnapshot doc;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<String> upcoming_seven_days;
  CollectionReference meetings;
  FirestoreService _firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Dashboard(),
    MeetingList(
      meeting: meetings,
    ),
    EventList(),
    Chat(),
    Profile(),
  ];

  static const List<Widget> _appBarText = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Dashboard',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
        fontSize: 26,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'Meetings',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
        fontSize: 26,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'Events',
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 26),
    ),
    Text(
      'Chat',
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 26),
    ),
    Text(
      'Profile',
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 26),
    ),
  ];

  Future getMeetings() async {
    CollectionReference meet =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('meetings');
    setState(() {
      meetings = meet;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    //setCurrentUserID(widget.currentUser.uid);
    getMeetings();
    //setCurrentUserData(doc.data());
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: _appBarText.elementAt(_selectedIndex)),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
              title: Text('Dashboard'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.people),
              title: Text('Meetings'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_view_day),
              title: Text('Events'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
              title: Text('Chat'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text('Profile'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.lightBlue[200],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        elevation: 8.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> MeetingList.dart

```
class MeetingList extends StatelessWidget {
  MeetingList({this.meeting});
  CollectionReference meeting;
  var userInfo;
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future getuserinfo() async {
    // final uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
    // userinfo = await firestoreService.getCurrentUserInfo(uid);
    // userinfo = userinfo.data().length;
    // //print(userinfo);
    // return uid;
    final uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;
    DocumentSnapshot user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('userProfiles')
        .doc(uid)
        .get();
    userInfo = user.data();
    return userInfo;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference meetings =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('meetings');
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getuserinfo(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return LoadingIndicator();
        } else {
          return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: meetings.snapshots(),
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Something went wrong');
              }

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return LoadingIndicator();
              }

              return new ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  String meetingRole = document.data()['role'];
                  var userRole = userInfo['role'];
                  print(userRole);
                  if (meetingRole == 'all' || meetingRole == userRole) {
                    return Meeting_Card(
                      meeting: document.data(),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container();
                  }
                }).toList(),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting error in `Home.dart` file in MeetingList component where i am passing the data. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting? That would be a good way to start checking what the issue may be

Comment: @rsalinas thank you ! It’s solved